# Visual Studio 2013 - How to link/include other libraries in my own library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, shared-libraries, static-libraries, building

I want to create library (with my own code) which will use **and include** other libraries. The problem is that every time i want to use it's not enough to link my library but i also have to link all libraries that are used by my own.

So if my library uses - e.g - GLFW, GLEW and others, each project that wants to use code from my own library has to link to them too.

Is there a way where i can tell compiler/linker to add those 3rd party libraries to my own so i would need only to link one?

I'm working on Visual Studio 2013 (Community) and i'd prefer to build it as static library then dynamic, but as far as i see static library project can't even link other libraries. Do i have to build it as dnamic lib? Or is there some trick to get it done?

I hope i presented the problem well enough to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

In your library source code, you can try and add the following:

```
#pragma comment (lib, "your_other_library")
```

Then this will implicitly link in the library without you having to explicitly specify it using the linker settings.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153901

Comment: The `#pragma` shouldn't bloat the code.  For the second item, it looks like gcc doesn't have such a `#pragma`.

Comment: I meant that if someone uses different compiler than MSVC then they don't really need that when i reffered to it as 'bloat' ;).

For the second question - i know that GCC doesnt have #pragma, what i asked is is there another solution to achieve "merging/linking to other static libraries" in library? I'm asking becouse i've never done it before and i would like to provide solution for those using GCC to build it like that too.

Comment: Also i prefer project settings rather then non-portable piece of code, though it's only my point of view.

Comment: Well for gcc you may not have a choice but document the libraries to link to.

Comment: Ok i was to fast to call it working. I'm trying for some time to use this approach and however i wont code it, it just doesnt work. It seems that it worked becouse i forgot to delete .lib files before compiling... Judging by file size etc. MSVC compiler just ignores it when building static library.